# Prove that the Differential Operator is Linear and Bounded

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\colon C^1([a,b])\longrightarrow C([a,b])$ where $C^1([a,b])$ is endowed with the norm $\|u\|_{1,\infty}:=\|u\|_{\infty}+\|u'\|_{\infty}$ and $C([a,b])$ with the supremum norm $\| u\|_{\infty}=\sup_{x\in[a,b]}|u(x)|$.

I proved that $A$ is bounded and linear. The linearity is an obvious result of standard analysis, so i skip it here. The operator is bounded, because

$\|A\|=\sup_{u\in C^1([a,b])\\
\|u\|_\infty =1}\|Au\|_\infty$ and it follows from the boundedness of continous functions on compact intervals, and using $\|u\|_{1,\infty}=1$, that
$\|A\|=\sup_{u\in C^1([a,b])\\
\|u\|_\infty =1}\|Au\|_\infty\le 1$, thus $A$ is bounded.

Furthermore, I have shown, that when considering $A=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\colon C([a,b])\longrightarrow C([a,b])$ both endowed with the supremum norm, the operator $A$ is not bounded anymore.

My question is: Can I find a norm on $C([a,b])$ such that $A$ is bounded?

If I am not mistaken, this should not be possible, since I have no control over the derivatives when consiering only continuous functions. I could find a nowhere differentiable functionon $[a,b]$ and regardless of the norm it can not be finite. Is my reasoning correct? Is there a better way to see this?

Comment: In what sense are you considering $A$ to be defined on $C([a,b])$? the classical derivative doesn't make sense on the entire of this space.

Comment: Differential operators are exactly the most basic example of linear unbounded operator. This fact is the reason why differential equations are often studied by converting them to *integral* equations: indeed, under general assumptions, the inverse of a differential operator can be thought of as an integral operator.

Comment: @RhysSteele I was wondering the same, I got the exercise out of a script. But I think it can be fixed by considering $C^1$ instead of just $C$.